# How to use System.Threading.Thread in Powershell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I need to port a C# application to Powershell. The application uses Threads to do heavy work and I need to keep the port of the application as close as possible to the original C# application. The problem is that I cannot spawn a new Thread by using **System.Threading.Thread** because **System.Threading.ThreadStart** is asking for **2** parameters in Powershell whereas the C# code only asks for **1** in the code because it is a delegate.

Here is a minimal class example in C# of spawning a Thread

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingTest
{
    class ThreadingTest
    {
        public delegate void UpdateElementCallback(string message);

        public ThreadingTest() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread));
            newThread.Start();
        }

        private void UpdateElement(string message) {
            Console.WriteLine(message + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        private void MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread() {
            UpdateElement("Hello from Thread ");
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs on an example run

```
Hello from Thread 1
Hello from Thread 4
```

Here is a non-working port to Powershell code that I tried

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Threading

class ThreadingTest {

    [Action[String]]$UpdateElementCallback = 
    {
        param([String]$message) 
        $callBackThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        "$message $callBackThread" | Out-Host
    }

    # Constructor
    ThreadingTest() {
        # Get current thread id
        $currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        # Print current thread id
        "Hello from Thread $currentThread" | Out-Host

        # Create a new thread (This line fails)
        $newThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::new([System.Threading.ThreadStart]::new($this.UpdateElementCallback))

        $newThread.Start
    }
}

$ThreadingTestObject = [ThreadingTest]::new()
```

Which outputs on an example run

```
Hello from Thread 21
MethodException: .../ThreadingTest.ps1:21:9
Line |
  21 |          $newThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::new([System.Threading …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "1".
```

The Powershell call to create a new **ThreadingStart** object has the following signature

**`System.Threading.ThreadStart new(System.Object object, System.IntPtr method)`**

What do I have to pass as parameters to make it work? What has to be the **System.Object** and what has to be the **System.IntPtr** passed as the arguments to make it work?

I want to make a note that I need to keep the code as close as possible as the original. I tried Start-Job and Runspaces. Runspaces worked, but it requires a lot of boilerplate. I would like to know if there is a way to make it work by using **System.Threading.Thread**

Comment: Can you use pre-built libraries?
`https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-run-c-code-from-within-powershell/`

Comment: If you're more comfortable with doing it in C# just have the libraries handle the thread creation and have some sort of object output to PowerShell to handle

Comment: i personally can not not recommend do migrate this to native powershell code. do this in a binary powershell module

Comment: Instead of porting the code to Powershell you can use add-type to load the c# source code as it is. As an alternative you van also load a compiled (dll) version of this code and still use it from Powershell. To answer the part about the intptr: it wants to have the pointer of your delegate.

Comment: @Riley Carney Thanks. Invoking C# and using the returned thread object works.

Comment: No problem @g_l. glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround found is to use C# to create a **System.Threading.Thread** object there and pass it to Powershell. Then use the thread object in Powershell as normal.

### Invoking C# from Powershell and using System.Threading.Thread

**Notes**: This code only works on **Powershell 7**. Previous versions throw an error that they cannot convert the method in the class to an Action.

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingTest
{
    public class ThreadCreator
    {
        public Thread CreateAThread(ThreadStart threadStart) {
            return new Thread(threadStart);
        }

        public ThreadStart CreateAThreadStart(Action threadStart) {
            return new ThreadStart(threadStart);
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 

class ThreadingTestClass {

    $ThreadCreator
    [System.Threading.Thread] $NewThread
    [bool] $finishCountingThread = $false
    [int] $ClassThreadId

    # Constructor
    ThreadingTestClass() {
        # Get the current thread id
        $this.ClassThreadId = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        # Print current thread id
        Write-Host "Hello from " -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Thread $($this.ClassThreadId)" -ForegroundColor Green
        # Create a ThreadCreator object
        $this.ThreadCreator = Invoke-Expression "[ThreadingTest.ThreadCreator]::new()"
        # Get a [System.Threading.Thread] object from the C# code to run '[Void] MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread()' in another thread
        $this.NewThread = $this.ThreadCreator.CreateAThread($this.ThreadCreator.CreateAThreadStart($this.MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread))
        # Start the thread
        $this.NewThread.Start()
        # Wait for user to press Escape. This 'do until' is executed while the other thread is running in the background. It doesn't wait for $this.NewThread to finish
        do {
            $keyPressed = [System.Console]::ReadKey().Key 
        } until ($keyPressed -eq [System.ConsoleKey]::Escape)
        # Set the $finishCountingThread variable to stop counting
        $this.finishCountingThread = $true;
        # Wait for the thread to finish gracefully before ending
        $this.NewThread.Join()
    }

    [Void] MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread() {
        # Get the current thread id
        $currentThreadID = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        # Say hello from the thread this method is running on
        Write-Host "Hello from " -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadId" -ForegroundColor Blue
        # Count from 0 to 10000
        for ($i = 0; $i -le 10000; $i++) {
            # Check boolean to know whether to finish counting or not
            if($this.finishCountingThread) {
                Write-Host "`nFinishing spawned " -NoNewline
                Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadID..." -ForegroundColor Blue
                break 
            }
            # Print on the console the current value of $i
            Write-Host "`rPress ESC to stop spawned " -NoNewline
            Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadID " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue
            Write-Host "and quit program: " -NoNewline 
            Write-Host "[Counting $i in Thread $currentThreadID] " –NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue
            Write-Host "Keys are being listened to on " -NoNewline
            Write-Host "Thread $($this.ClassThreadId)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
        }

        # Check if the counting finished before the user pressed Escape
        if (-Not $this.finishCountingThread) {
            "`nCounting finished" | Out-Host
            "Press ESC to quit program..." | Out-Host
        }
    }
}
# Set cursor visible to false to see colors without a jittering cursor
[System.Console]::CursorVisible = $false
"`n`n" | Out-Host
$ThreadingTestClassObject = [ThreadingTestClass]::new()
"`n`n" | Out-Host
```

The code invokes C# code to create an object that has methods to create a Thread. Two of the methods are called to create a **System.Threading.Thread object** and return it. Then the thread object can be used from Powershell. Because the passed method to the spawned thread (**MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread**) is within the Powershell class, the same has access to the class' Properties even though it is in another thread.

Output when it runs until the end:
[image]
Output when **ESC** is pressed to stop counting
[image]

### Alternative - Using System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

The following doesn't answer the question which was how to use **System.Threading.Thread** in Powershell, but it is another solution for multithreading without invoking any C# code and without using Runspaces or Jobs. It uses a BackgroundWorker as shown below. It is useful for when a Form or WPF GUI is being used. The output is the same as the in the other code.

**Notes**: This code only works on **Powershell 7**. Previous versions throw an error that they cannot convert the method in the class to an Action.

```
class ThreadingTestClass {

    [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker] $BackgroundWorker
    [bool] $finishCountingThread = $false
    [int] $ClassThreadId

    # Constructor
    ThreadingTestClass() {
        # Get the current thread id
        $this.ClassThreadId = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        # Print current thread id
        Write-Host "Hello from " -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Thread $($this.ClassThreadId)" -ForegroundColor Green

        # Create a BackgroundWorker object, set the event and set it to support cancellation
        $this.BackgroundWorker = [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker]::new()
        $this.BackgroundWorker.add_DoWork($this.MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread)
        $this.BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = $true
        # Run the method 'MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread' in another thread
        $this.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

        # Wait for user to press Escape. This 'do until' is executed while the other thread is running in the background. It doesn't wait for $this.BackgroundWorker to finish
        do {
            $keyPressed = [System.Console]::ReadKey().Key 
        } until ($keyPressed -eq [System.ConsoleKey]::Escape)

        # Set the $finishCountingThread variable to stop counting
        $this.finishCountingThread = $true
        if ($this.BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation -and $this.BackgroundWorker.IsBusy) {
            # Cancel the background worker work
            $this.BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()
            # while loop only needed if there is no GUI or anything else preventing PS from continuing and trying to exit
            while ($this.BackgroundWorker.IsBusy) {
                # Do nothing. Block calling thread and wait for the Background worker to finish cancelling
                # Otherwise, Powershell will continue to execute code further and it can
                # end code execution while there is another thread in the background
                # That will cause an exception and a crash
                # GUIs usually prevent PowerShell from exiting
                # for which this may not be needed in a Form or WPF application
            }
        }
    }

    [Void] MethodToBeCalledFromAnotherThread([Object]$sender, [System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs]$e) {
        # Get the current thread id
        $currentThreadID = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        # Say hello from the thread this method is running on
        Write-Host "Hello from " -NoNewline
        Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadId" -ForegroundColor Blue
        # Count from 0 to 10000
        for ($i = 0; $i -le 10000; $i++) {
            # Check boolean to know whether to finish counting or not
            if($this.finishCountingThread) {
                Write-Host "`nFinishing spawned " -NoNewline
                Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadID..." -ForegroundColor Blue
                break 
            }
            # Print on the console the current value of $i
            Write-Host "`rPress ESC to stop spawned " -NoNewline
            Write-Host "Thread $currentThreadID " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue
            Write-Host "and quit program: " -NoNewline 
            Write-Host "[Counting $i in Thread $currentThreadID] " –NoNewline -ForegroundColor Blue
            Write-Host "Keys are being listened to on " -NoNewline
            Write-Host "Thread $($this.ClassThreadId)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
        }

        # Check if the counting finished before the user pressed Escape
        if (-Not $this.finishCountingThread) {
            "`nCounting finished" | Out-Host
            "Press ESC to quit program..." | Out-Host
        }
    }
}
# Set cursor visible to false to see colors without a jittering cursor
[System.Console]::CursorVisible = $false
"`n`n" | Out-Host
$ThreadingTestClassObject = [ThreadingTestClass]::new()
"`n`n" | Out-Host
```